# gcloud storage transfer service is very slow?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I use gcloud cli to do it.

```
 gcloud transfer jobs create https://<azure resource>.blob.core.windows.net/container/6g/  gs://<storage bucket>/ --source-creds-file=D:\azureCred.json
```

The following table shows how long it takes to transfer one file.

| file size | from  azure blob to gcloud storage(gcloud storage transfer) | from gcloud storage to azure blob (azcopy)
| -------- | -------|-------|
| 34.7M   |  21secs ~ 31secs |
| 6.48G   |  13mins11secs ~ 29mins17secs | 12secs |
GCloud storage transfer service is very slow , but azcopy is very fast.

So I want to know why gcloud storage service takes so much time, and what can I do to increase speed?

Comment: This isn't a programming problem that we can help you with.  The only thing we can say is that you need a faster internet connection to the region where your bucket is.

Answer (score 0):

One way to increase speed is to run multiple Transfer Jobs in parallel on distinct prefix. You can use include and exclude prefix to achieve that. For single large object, there not much you do make storage transfer service go faster.